# Custom Pagination shows same posts on each page

Tags: pagination, twitter-bootstrap

I followed a [tutorial](https://brinidesigner.com/wordpress-custom-pagination-for-bootstrap/) which adds boostrap pagination to a theme. I added this code into my functions.php and it seems work. However, each page shows the same posts? In my admin settings I have the max number of posts per page to 2. I have a total of 3 posts so on the first page I see two posts but when I go to the second page It shows the same two instead of the third one. Is there something I am missing?

The code in questions is:

```
function custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    $pages = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type' => 'array',
        'prev_next' => TRUE,
        'prev_text' => '&larr; Previous',
        'next_text' => 'Next &rarr;',
            ));
    if (is_array($pages)) {
        $current_page = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ($pages as $i => $page) {
            if ($current_page == 1 && $i == 0) {
                echo "<li class='active'>$page</li>";
            } else {
                if ($current_page != 1 && $current_page == $i) {
                    echo "<li class='active'>$page</li>";
                } else {
                    echo "<li>$page</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

I am using the following loop in the archive for a custom post type (archive-news.php):

```
    <?php $news = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'news'
        ));  ?>

    <?php while($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post(); ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </h2>
        <p class="lead">
            <?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>
            by <?php echo $author ?>
        </p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Posted on <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#">
            <?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <hr>

        <?php if(get_field('news_content')): ?>
            <p class="description"><?php echo get_field('news_content'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

        <hr>

    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Please try with `$current_page = ( get_query_var('page') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('page');` this piece of code. I want to see what happens.

Comment: nothing, it stays the same.

Comment: in what template(s) are you using the code? what is the code of the query in the template?

Comment: @Michael I updated the question with the response to your question. hope that helps

Comment: why do you create a new query in the template rather than run the default main query? the problem is that you don't pass any pagination parameters to your query, you only set post type, so you will always get the first page of results. when you use the main query, all of this happens automatically.

Comment: @Milo what do you mean? Do you mind expanding a bit? Sorry, I am new to wordpress dev as you can see.

Comment: The main query is always generated automatically by WordPress, you only need to run the main loop `while( have_posts() ) ...` etc.. You're creating a new query, `$news`, and running the loop on that query: `while($news->have_posts())`, this is the root of your problem. There is no connection between that query and the page it's running on, the pagination parameters aren't automatically passed to that query.